# Should eesha salaah be delayed?

Tags: salat

The *eesha* salaah timing in the *masjid* in my neighborhood is usually very late. In fact during winters (like currently) they delay the salaah to the extent that sometimes it is nearly 35 minutes later than the neighboring *masajid*. So much so that I prefer going to the other *masjid* and completing my *eesha* salaah there.

I am not aware why they delay *eesha* salaah to such an extent that it becomes inconvenient for everyone (or maybe just some), however I think this may have something to do with hadith of the Messenger (SAWS) that the [*eesha* salaah would be the last thing he would do before retiring](http://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/2#36).

I have a feeling that we may quite possible have misunderstood the import of this hadith: he would not intentionally delay his salaah; rather it was the last thing he did before retiring, regardless of the time. There is a difference between the two statements: it is not automatically implied that the Messenger (SAWS) would *delay* his salaah. This is especially telling since he (SAWS) always insisted on praying as early as possible, and I don't think *eesha* salaah should be excluded from this injunction.

I would be grateful if anyone with knowledge in this area could throw some more light on this. My knowledge in this matter is sketchy at best.

Comment: Perhaps they delay it to offer more time for people to come?

Comment: Possibly; however this practice is seen in quite a few other masajids. And the sunnah is to offer prayers at the earliest possible time and not delay it according to people's availability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the *masjid* is doing is not wrong, as there is clear precedent in the sunnah to delay the night prayer:

> [The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) delayed the `Isha' prayer
>   till midnight and then he offered the prayer and said, "The people
>   prayed and slept but you have been in prayer as long as you have been
>   waiting for it (the prayer)."](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/9#48)

It is also reported that the prophet *preferred* to delay the night prayer, but refrained from doing so (regularly) because [it would cause too much hardship](http://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/2#25) on the *ummah*.

So while I wouldn't say that it *should* be delayed, it *is* a recommendable action: Given that all the time spent waiting for a delayed prayer counts as being in prayer, it does benefit you to pray thus.

Comment: Jazakallahu khairan for the answer. Very satisfactory.